# Hover works in one case but not in another

Tags: html, css, hover

The following HTML and CSS code snippet works fine:

```css
.dropdown:hover .features-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #B2D6FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;

}
```

```html
<li class='dropdown'>Features ▾
  <ul class='features-menu'>
    <li><a href='#'>Harder</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Better</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Faster</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Stronger</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

But if I try enclosing the text `Features` in either a `span` or a `div`, that is,

```
<li class='dropdown'><span>Features ▾</span>
```

and make the following change to my CSS concerning the hover

```
.dropdown span:hover .features-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #B2D6FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 780px;

}
```

The hover no longer renders. Why is this method not working? I thought maybe it was because span was an inline element but then I tried it with `div` also and it still failed to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you need to understand CSS selectors more.

Lets explain the first (working CSS) selector `.dropdown:hover .features-menu` = Select all elements with class `dropdown` when they are in `hover` state  and set up properties for `features-menu` class ***inside*** that `.dropdown`

Now the second CSS `.dropdown span:hover .features-menu` reads: Select all `span` elements ***within*** class `dropdown` when they are in `hover` state  and set up properties for `features-menu` class ***inside*** that `.dropdown span`

Since in your working example `.dropdown` element includes `.features-menu` it's OK. But in second case `.dropdown span` element doesn't include `.features-menu`

Using "sibling" selector might help here:

```css
.dropdown span:hover ~ .features-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #B2D6FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px
}
```

```html
<li class='dropdown'><span>Features ▾</span>
  <ul class='features-menu'>
    <li><a href='#'>Harder</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Better</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Faster</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Stronger</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is how your markup looks like:

```html
<li class='dropdown'><span>Features ▾</span>
  <ul class='features-menu'>           
  <li><a href='#'>Harder</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Better</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Faster</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Stronger</a></li>
  </ul> 
</li>
```

> the hover no longer renders. Why is this method not working? I thought maybe it was because span was an inline element but then I tried it with div also and it still failed to render.

This CSS declaration: `.dropdown span:hover .features-menu` will only apply to `.features-menu` which is a child element of `span`. However on this case, `.features-menu` is a sibling of span and that's why it's not working.

**You can try using the [adjacent sibling selector (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) instead:**

```css
.dropdown span:hover + .features-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #B2D6FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;

  position: absolute;      
  top: 50px;
  left: 780px;

}
```

Or just don't make any change to your previous CSS declaration:

```css
.dropdown:hover .features-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #B2D6FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;

  position: absolute;      
  top: 50px;
  left: 780px;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your original CSS should work with the new `<span>` introduced. The CSS selector for the hover, `.dropdown:hover .features-menu` will still target the `<span>`'s parent element, meaning that the hover effect should still work as the parent element still exists.

I've put this on a codepen to demonstrate:
https://codepen.io/littlefinger42/pen/ebWYJP